# Compiling Z3 for OCaml

Tags: compilation, ocaml, z3

I tried to compile the OCaml version for [Z3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/), however when I build it, it always shows a bunch of error and warning.

These are several of the errors:

```
z3_stubs.c:7384: error: storage size of `_ctxs' isn't known
z3_stubs.c:7385: error: `camlidl_ctx' undeclared (first use in this function)
z3_stubs.c:7385: error: expected `;' before `_ctx'
```

I dont really get it, I just try to run the `build.cmd`, and the error happens, anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [camlidl](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/camlidl) installed?

Comment: I dont get it, the camlidl will generate the stub code, wont it? I have already found the stub files there, which are `z3_stubs.c` and `z3_theory_stubs.c`

Comment: But camlidl needs runtime support. Can the compiler find camlidlruntime.h and libcamlidl.a?